# Opening a new window in spaces with Mac OS X

Tags: macos, osx-spaces

I use a Mac together with Spaces which permits more than a single desktop.

I have a problem though, whenever I click on let's say a new browser window (loading firefox), spaces jumps to a desktop which already has firefox open. Is it possible to make osx open a new firefox window (or any other application), if it does not exist in the current desktop, instead of moving to the desktop?

Answer (score 4):

Note that the preference has moved in Lion.  It's now under **Mission Control**.

Answer (score 3):

Try unchecking the checkbox at the bottom in *System Preferences » Exposé & Spaces*.

[image]

Remember to set your browser to open links in new windows instead of new tabs of existing windows.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a great and easy solution for FireFox which lets you open links a a new window in the current space:
Use the FireFox Add-On "TabMixPlus". In the TabMixPlus-settings, under "Links", there is an option called (translated from german) "for links from other applications, use different settings", and there you can choose "New window".
For me, when I click on a link in a PDF file or in a message in Thunderbird, this now opens a new FireFox window in the current space!
TabMixPlus is available via the Add-Ons menu in FireFox, or look at http://tmp.garyr.net/