# How do I reserve a Space to a single application? (Snow Leopard Spaces)

Tags: macos, osx-spaces

Once in a while I try to use Spaces in OS X, but I quit after a little because I can't find the way to make Spaces behave the way I want.
I would like to emulate the Lion full screen feature, so I want to reserv a space only for an application. Any other unassigned apps should open in another space.
Is there a way to do that or I have to manually assign all the applications?

PS: I'm not looking for a third party application, I can accept the answer only if it's a OSX built-in trick/hack

Comment: The preferences for Spaces looked like [this](http://superuser.com/questions/262780/opening-a-new-window-in-spaces-with-mac-os-x/262781#262781), right? And if you open a new window in an unassigned application, it opened in the current space, not a specific one?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but I can't see a way to do that, other than going to a different space before opening another program, doing what you need to do, and going back to the other space.

As you said, there propably is a 3rd-party app for this.